# WebDriver -- Unable to find dynamic span attribute

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

A website that I am testing at the moment derives value from the DB and it's dynamic. I need to be able to fetch the value from DB and validate that against what is present in UI which will not be static. The text I am trying to verify is below, for this, I need to identify the element and verify text by comparing the data from DB and what is present on the screen. The specific text here in this example is "Resource". The same span is repeated several times with different values in the same screen. Please help as to how can I identify the element as well validating against DB. I am new to selenium WebDriver.

```
<span class="card-title grey-text">Resource</span>
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: cssSelector : span.card-title grey-text  or xpath would be : //span[text()='Resource']

Comment: @kish Core trials and the error stack trace (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

If span value "Resource" is dynamic every time, try to retrieve it by following :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='card-title grey-text']")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could gather all spans in list and validate against DB values:

```
int iCnt=0;
List<String> listDB = new ArrayList();

public List<String> DBconnection(){
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/t", "", "");

    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    String sql = ("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id;");
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

    if(rs.next()) { 
       listDB.add(rs.getString("second_column_name"));
    }

    con.close();
    return list;
}
```

//testing part

```
public void testAginstDb(List<String> listDB){
    List<WebElement> listSpan = 
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.card-title.grey-text"));

    for(String itemDb : listDB){
        for (WebElement item : listSpan) {
           if(item.getText().equals(rs.value())){
              iCnt+=1;
              break;
           } 
        }

    Assert.equals(list.size(), iCNT);

    }
}
```

Sorry code was written from head, maybe there are some mistakes, essentially I would make that approach.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone! before I could implement any of the suggested methods, developer kindly agreed to include unique IDs which made the job easier. Apologies for not replying for so long, just couldn't get back in time.